# shortening Javascript number

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am looking for an efficient way to cut floating number at Javascript which are long. I need this because my output for taking percentage of two numbers can be sometimes like 99.4444444 while I am only interested in the first 2 digits after "." such as 99.44

My current percentage taking function for 2 numbers:

```
function takePercentage(x,y){
     return (x /y) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
Math.round( myfloatvalue*100 ) / 100
```

Comment: this works with google visualisation api table generation while "toFixed(2)" somehow doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

You can use number.[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
function takePercentage(x,y){
     return ((x /y) * 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Note that toFixed fails to round numbers in IE, which can combine with floating-point inaccuracies to give unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

```
function takePercentage(x,y){
     n = (x /y) * 100;
     return n.toPrecision(2);
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: this isn't correct . 99.345.toPrecision(2) for example yields "99"

Comment: toPresicion returns the number rounded to a precision of **significant digits**, i.e.: `123.456.toPrecision(3) == 123;`, `123.456.toPrecision(2) == 120;`, `123.456.toPrecision(4) == 123.5;` more info here: http://is.gd/3zchw, you should also use the `var` statement to declare `n`, if you don't n is declared globally